# which code is more efficient? calling twice a macro or just assigning macro to a variable and use it twice?

Tags: c

From the below "C" code snippets which one is more efficient (1 or 2) and Why? Please shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

```
//I am doing some operation with this macro.
 #define ERRMAP( sts ) ((A_AB( sts ) < FIRST_ERR) ? \
                         sts : \
                         ((A_AB( sts ) > A_AB( LAST_ERR )) ? \
                         sts : \
                         sts_to_errno_m[A_AB( sts ) - FIRST_ERR]))


    //Code snippet 1
       int some_fun (int sts) {

               int i = ERRMAP( sts );
               printf(" sts = %d", i);
               return i;
        }


    //Code snippet 2
        int some_fun (int sts) {

               printf(" sts = %d", ERRMAP( sts ));
               return (ERRMAP( sts ));
        }
```

Comment: Can you mention why `ERRMAP` is a macro not a function? Why does it need textual substitution?

Comment: Remember that C macro is fairly simple text replacement. It being a macro is not really relevant to efficiency.

Comment: Already this macro is awfully bad: it evaluates its argument several times, which you should never do when you can avoid it. An inline function would be much more appropriate and can avoid you a lot of headache when you have to trace spurious bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `A_ABS` is also a function like macro! The basic trick is to work it out in your head into pseudo machine code - lets say that `A_ABS` has a similar complexity and doesn't call any more things - then I would put each of them at about 20 op codes making a total of 40 - using them and assigning to a value then using that value twice would be 42 - while "calling" twice would be 80 so you work it out.

**BTW** - you should only even think about doing this sort of macro, (i.e. function like), if you have tried using a function and your profiler has said it is one of the main reasons that your code is either too big or too slow.  The reasons:

1. Errors in macros are hard for the compiler to report the location of - you have 5 lines of up to 80 characters but any compiler errors will just be reported where you "call" the code.
2. You are defeating type checking which is one of the major benefits of C/C++
3. Debugging other than as machine code is impossible as you can not
   step through a macro.
4. It is a maintenance nightmare.
5. Compiler optimisers will often not do well on it.
6. Code checkers can not work well on macros
7. MISRA and other compilence checkers will fail your code.
8. It is usually unnecessary!

Answer (score 3):

Please don't worry about "most efficient" without having first done some sort of measurement that it matters.  Also "efficient" can mean many different things.  Efficient in terms of execution time?  Code size?  Memory usage?  "Efficient" is not a synonym for "fastest".

Rather than worrying about which is fastest, think about which way is clearest.  The most expensive time is programmer time.

Comment: I agree with you for the most part, but wouldn't you say this doesn't apply when you are actually reducing the big O performance and not just making micro optimizations

Comment: In this context, when OP is not familiar with how macros work and how compilers optimize away auto variables, introducing the idea of big O is outside the scope.

Comment: Yeah I just thought a clarification would be nice, big O is pretty important

Comment: Thank you Andy Lester for your thought! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
int some_fun (int sts) {
    printf(" sts = %d", ERRMAP( sts ));
    return (ERRMAP( sts ));
}
```

Someday if ERRMAP is modified to have a side-effect you'll get different results between what's printed and returned.

Also doing the calculation once is a good idea. This is best whether ERRMAP is a function or a macro: `int i = ERRMAP( sts );`